# RFID-RC522 with pic16F628A

Tags: microcontroller, pic, rfid

I want to connect a RFID-RC522 with pic16F628A microcontroller. The only tutorials I could find are those that have RFID-RC522 connected with arduino. The reason why I want to use RFID-RC522, is because I already had it laying around my house, for arduino projects.

The only thing I want it to do is to make it turn on a LED the first time the tag is scanned and turn it of the second time the tag is scanned. Can someone give me a link or instruction on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what difficulty do you have with following arduino instructions? ... the pic16F628A code would be almost the same

Comment: I don't have problems following the arduino instructions. I've done some arduino projects with it myself. But does that also mean that the library(or however it's called in mplab) you need for the pic is the same.

Comment: i could be wrong about this, but i would expect a pic16F628A library to be available for the RFID-RC522 along with example code

Comment: Well, then I will try with the arduino code. Hope the same code will get the result.